# Pasar elseif a un switch

Tags: php

Hola buenas tardes tengo elseis para cachar las los tipos de valores que obtengo en la variable $prefix, pero quisiera simplificar todo el código por un switch, ¿Existe forma de pasar mi código a un switch?

> Código

```
if ($prefix == "02" || $prefix  == "03" || $prefix  == "05" || $prefix == "06" || $prefix == "07" || $prefix == "08" || $prefix== "09") {
                $TIPO_TEL_DESTINO = "SERVICIOS VERTICALES";
                $TIPO_TRAFICO = "SERVICIOS VERTICALES";
            } elseif ($prefix == "1" || $prefix == "1450" || $prefix == "1808" || $prefix == "1809" || $prefix == "1829" || $prefix == "1849" || $prefix == "2" || $prefix == "3" || $prefix == "33" || $prefix == "34" || $prefix == "39" || $prefix == "4" || $prefix == "44" || $prefix == "49" || $prefix == "5" || $prefix == "53" || $prefix == "55" || $prefix == "6" || $prefix == "61" || $prefix == "7" || $prefix == "8" || $prefix == "9") {
                $TIPO_TEL_DESTINO = "LD_INTERNACIONAL";
                $TIPO_TRAFICO = "LD_INTERNACIONAL";
            } elseif ($prefix == "52") {
                $TIPO_TEL_DESTINO = "FIJO";
                $TIPO_TRAFICO = "FIJO";
            } elseif ($prefix == "521") {
                $TIPO_TEL_DESTINO = "CELULAR";
                $TIPO_TRAFICO = "CELULAR";
            } elseif ($prefix == "LRN_MOVIL") {
                $TIPO_TEL_DESTINO = "CELULAR";
                $TIPO_TRAFICO = "CELULAR";
            } elseif ($prefix == "LRN_911") {
                $TIPO_TEL_DESTINO = "LRN_911";
                $TIPO_TRAFICO = "LRN_911";
            } elseif ($prefix == "LRN_FIJO") {
                $TIPO_TEL_DESTINO = "FIJO";
                $TIPO_TRAFICO = "FIJO";
            } elseif ($prefix == "onnet_in") {
                $TIPO_TEL_DESTINO = "ONNET_IN";
                $TIPO_TRAFICO = "ONNET_IN";
            } elseif ($prefix == "onnet_out" || $prefix == "onnet_out") {
                // cacho los DID_SERVNET y Onnet_out
                $TIPO_TEL_DESTINO = $prefix;
                $TIPO_TRAFICO = $prefix;
            } else {
                $TIPO_TEL_DESTINO = $prefix;
                $TIPO_TRAFICO = $prefix;
            }
```

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lo puedes hacer de esta forma:

```
switch(true){
    case ($prefix == "02" || $prefix  == "03" || $prefix  == "05" || $prefix == "06" || $prefix == "07" || $prefix == "08" || $prefix== "09"):
                $TIPO_TEL_DESTINO = "SERVICIOS VERTICALES";
                $TIPO_TRAFICO = "SERVICIOS VERTICALES";
                break;
    case ($prefix == "1" || $prefix == "1450" || $prefix == "1808" || $prefix == "1809" || $prefix == "1829" || $prefix == "1849" || $prefix == "2" || $prefix == "3" || $prefix == "33" || $prefix == "34" || $prefix == "39" || $prefix == "4" || $prefix == "44" || $prefix == "49" || $prefix == "5" || $prefix == "53" || $prefix == "55" || $prefix == "6" || $prefix == "61" || $prefix == "7" || $prefix == "8" || $prefix == "9"):
                $TIPO_TEL_DESTINO = "LD_INTERNACIONAL";
                $TIPO_TRAFICO = "LD_INTERNACIONAL";
                break;
//Agregas tus demas casos.

    default:
                $TIPO_TEL_DESTINO = $prefix;
                $TIPO_TRAFICO = $prefix;
                break;
}
```

Lo de esta forma:

```
switch($prefix){
    case "02":
    case "03":
    case "05":
                $TIPO_TEL_DESTINO = "SERVICIOS VERTICALES";
                $TIPO_TRAFICO = "SERVICIOS VERTICALES";
                break;
//agregas el resto de tus casos
    default:
                $TIPO_TEL_DESTINO = $prefix;
                $TIPO_TRAFICO = $prefix;
                break;
}
```